# problems running Docker container in Cypress

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, automated-tests, cypress

The docker container 'will build' but for some reason 'will not run'.  I've trying to resolve this but I think I need a fresh pair of eyes on it.

Here is the code:

Docker file:

```
FROM cypress/included:6.8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN $(npm bin)/ cypress  verify
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress
```

The docker ignore file

```
node_modules
```

The docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services: 
    e2e:
        image: cypress
        build: .
        container_name: cypress
        command: 
            npx cypress run
```

I got the following error message in my terminal

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
Building e2e
[+] Building 293.8s (9/10)                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                        0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/cypress/included:6.8.0                           0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/cypress/included:6.8.0                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.14kB                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                               0.0s
 => [3/6] COPY . /app                                                                       0.1s
 => [4/6] RUN npm install                                                                 292.0s
 => ERROR [5/6] RUN $(npm bin)/ cypress  verify                                             1.4s
------                                                                                           
 > [5/6] RUN $(npm bin)/ cypress  verify:                                                        
#9 1.387 /bin/sh: 1: /app/node_modules/.bin/: Permission denied                                  
------                                                                                           
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c $(npm bin)/ cypress  verify]: exit code: 126                 
ERROR: Service 'e2e' failed to build
xxx-MacBook-Air CypressDocker %
```

@mosaad. I just tried your answer.  However I got the following error message

```
  => ERROR [5/6] RUN $(npm bin)/ cypress  verify                                             1.8s
------                                                                                           
 > [5/6] RUN $(npm bin)/ cypress  verify:
#9 1.705 /bin/sh: 1: /app/node_modules/.bin/: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c $(npm bin)/ cypress  verify]: exit code: 127
ERROR: Service 'e2e' failed to build
```

Answer (score 3):

You should copy *after* `npm install` so that node_modules are copied too.

This should work:

```
FROM cypress/included:6.8.0
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN $(npm bin)/ cypress verify
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress
```

Comment: Hi, I tried updated  the code and got an error message.  It's the last entry in my original question.

Comment: @fypnlp Try to delete `node_module` and run everything again

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to everyone who took a moment to take a look at my problem. I rewrote the docker-compose.yml file code again and it now works perfectly.   If this can help anyone in the future here is the corrected code.

```
FROM cypress/included:6.8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress
```